# Как вывести false вместо true в массиве?

Tags: javascript

```
var array1 = [true,  true,  true,  false,
          true,  true,  true,  true ,
          true,  false, true,  false,
          true,  false, false, true ,
          true,  true,  true,  true ,
          false, false, true,  true ];

function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
console.log(arrayOfSheep.filter(Boolean).length)
}

countSheeps(array1);
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы выводилось не true а false.Как можно сделать?

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` -> `.filter(!Boolean)` ?

Comment: тут выводится 17, а не true

Comment: @SwaD, это так не работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вызов `.filter(Boolean)` равносилен вызову

```
.filter(el => Boolean(el))
```

метод [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) возвращает те элементы, для которых `callback` вернул `true`.

В данном случае достаточно применить [`!` (логическое отрицание)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)

```
.filter(el => !Boolean(el))
```